# github actions repository dispatch "message": "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-actions

I am trying to create an actions workflow that can be triggered from an external event. Upon researching, found out I can do it through repository_dispatch.

I need to trigger the actions through python but I get this error and status code 400:

> {'message': 'Problems parsing JSON', 'documentation_url':
> 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event'}

I then serialized the payload dictionary to string with json.dumps() and the error changed to with code 422:

> {'message': 'Invalid request.\n\nFor 'links/0/schema',
> "{"event_type": "test", "client_payload": {"unit": false,
> "integration": true}}" is not an object.', 'documentation_url':
> 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event'}

Here's my code snippet that I constructer from the curl example provided in the docs

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/larwindcunha/<repo>/dispatches"
payload = {"event_type": "test", "client_payload": {"unit":False,"integration":True}}
header = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github+json", "Authorization": "token <my_token>"}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
resp = requests.post(url=url, headers=header, json=payload)
```

When I try running the curl command provided here - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event, I get the same error with code 400:

> {'message': 'Problems parsing JSON', 'documentation_url':
> 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event'}

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <MY_TOKEN_HERE>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/dispatches \
  -d '{"event_type":"on-demand-test","client_payload":{"unit":false,"integration":true}}'
```

Does you guys know if I'm doing something wrong here? Or is repository dispatch broken? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another user helped me with this answer -

```
payload = json.dumps(payload)
resp = requests.post(url=url, headers=header, json=payload)
```

> json.dumps() expects a Python data structure, serializes that as JSON,
> and returns it as a string. The json parameter for requests.post()
> expects a Python data structure, serializes that as JSON, and sends it
> as the post body. Seems familiar? The result is that you get JSON for
> a string that contains JSON.
>
> Remove the payload = json.dumps(payload) line and it should work.

I was trying to print(resp.json()) since I was getting a json response on error, but on successful post request, there was no response, and just got an JSON decoder error. This misled me as I assumed that some json data would be sent back in the response for positive case as it was for a negative one. Later when I checked my actions log, it was being triggered.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\dcunh\Documents\Code\Test\env_test\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 971, in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\dcunh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py",
> line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Users\dcunh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Users\dcunh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\dcunh\Documents\Code\Test\test.py", line 10, in 
> print(resp.json())   File "C:\Users\dcunh\Documents\Code\Test\env_test\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 975, in json
> raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos) requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
> (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot literally offer

```
-H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
```

as an element of your POST request.

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) is inviting you
to signup and request a personal token,
and then insert its value into that `<TOKEN>` placeholder.
It's a bit like seeing a form letter
that starts `Dear <insert-your-name-here>:` --
we anticipate that a sensible value will be substituted for the placeholder.

Comment: Yes, that's understood. I kept it as <TOKEN> for simplicity or a placeholder since I didn't want to expose sensitive data. 
I perhaps, should've put a disclaimer saying this. My bad.